# GPON simulation model in OMNET++

Tags: networking, omnet++, simulator

Is there any GPON (gigabit-capable passive optical network) simulation model available for OMNET++? or is there any other alternate free simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I had not seen the manual, I've been trying to compile it all week and it always gives me problems, apparently it is much more profitable to look for other software than compiling in ns-3, although the module seems quite complete.

Answer (score -1):

A basic implementation of (1G) Ethernet Passive Optical Network (EPON) for OMNeT++ 4.1 ( an older version, latest version being OMNET++ 6) is available. For more details check the EPON project page.

https://omnetpp.org/download-items/EPON.html

Other simulators:

From sourceforge page I did find
XG-PON module for the NS-3 network simulator. This module is designed and implemented with aim to provide a standards-compliant, configurable, and extensible module that can simulate XG-PON with reasonable speed and can support a wide range of research topics.

Like OMNET++, NS3 is also a widely used network simulator.

Comment: The XG-PON for NS-3 has many compilation issues.  I fixed few and it still says some functions are not implemented. Seems the one uploaded by authors is not complete code.

Comment: Hope you consulted the manual available at http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~xw2/xgpon4ns3manual.pdf There seems to be some changes required in installed ns3 as well.